# Why is Donald Trump positively rated in Africa?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, international-relations, public-opinion, africa

From a [report](https://www.theafricareport.com/13778/why-africa-gives-thumbs-up-to-donald-trumps-america/), I gained knowledge that Donald Trump is mostly liked in the African Continent in opposition to other regions like the European Continent! I know under Trump that there is a foreign policy as I've seen Trump's daughter with Kwesi Quartey. What is the reason for such positivity apart from African Nations always supporting the American Dream?

> There is one continent where Trump’s image is unscathed – Africa. Not all of Africa, of course. In the Maghreb, from Rabat to Tripoli and Cairo, the Trump administration’s popularity indices are at their lowest. Only 16% of Moroccans and Tunisians see value in Trump’s foreign policies. Overall, with an approval rate of 52%, Africa has a positive image of Trump’s America.
> ...
> Yet he is more popular in Africa than in any other region, according to a 25-nation survey by Pew, a pollster. Some 59% of Nigerians and 56% of Kenyans believe he is a positive influence on world affairs. South Africans are less keen: only 39% express confidence in Mr Trump.

Comment: Please do not include images or text without proper attribution.

Comment: Yes. There was a proper attribution, @Rick Smith. I commented about Kwesi and Trump's daughter in the question body. You're not the one asking the question, I am!

Comment: Respectfully, you provided a link to an article. That link did not include the posted image; therefore, a separate attribution is required for the image. You then added text not given in the article. Text that appears to have come from economist.com and not attributed.

Comment: Well. I agree with you on that part!

Comment: Can you make the edits, @Rick Smith

Comment: No, there are a few sources for the image. I don't know which source you used. Your search history should help. As for the text, Economist requires registration, I am not registered. The text showed in a search, which is why I said "appears to have".

Comment: This is not a full answer, but historical [trends](https://news.gallup.com/poll/183122/leadership-loses-ground-africa-asia.aspx) show that approval of the US in the African countries surveyed increased from 2007 until 2010, if not earlier, without any sign of a jump. So the election of the first Black US president, with a nominally less hawkish foreign policy outlook than Bush, did not move the needle much. However, in 2011, the year in which Obama started a small-scale war (essentially) in Libya, there was a 10% drop from the last year. It seems like the survey was probably done late enough.

Comment: That year began a decline in the approval of the US in the continent overall, one that has continued to this day, even perhaps levelling off somewhat in the Trump administration. So I do not have hard evidence—I have not yet found a survey that asked this question in even a single non-Libyan country—but I strongly suspect that approval of US "job performance" in Africa (and perhaps other regions), which is the actual question asked, is driven by relatively local actions, more so than by the personality and views of the US leaders.

Comment: @Obie2.0 That's pretty much the explanation given by the article OP linked to: that the Trump administration has been ignoring Africa, so the US's approval rating hasn't changed as much there as in other places. They do also hypothesize that his "shithole countries" comment didn't hit as hard in sub-saharan Africa since many people there have a poor opinion of their own countries themselves, but they don't provide any evidence for that

Comment: Did you see the “parade” (his word) they had for him in Nigeria?

Comment: Removed the image as its not really relevant to the question. You can find photos of Trump smiling next to Trudeau too - that doesn't tell us if he's popular in Canada.

Answer (score 5):

The same newspaper in a [different article](https://www.economist.com/middle-east-and-africa/2018/10/24/why-donald-trump-is-popular-in-africa) gives some of the reasons why President Trump is popular is Africa. The article mentions some drinkers praising Mr. Trump in a pub in Kenya for standing upto China. Also it says more Kenyans preferred American led world to a China led world. Another reason that those men drinking in the pub said is that Mr. Trump speaks what others think. A truck driver named Willie thinks Mr. Trump is honest.

Religion is a reason according to [Global Voices](https://globalvoices.org/2020/01/11/why-is-united-states-president-donald-trump-popular-in-nigeria/) for Mr. Trump's popularity amongst the 48% Christians in Nigeria.

Soon after President Trump made some dirty remarks on African countries (which they found really insulting), US ambassador to South Africa Lana Marks spoke in an interview which was reported by [BusinessTech.za](https://businesstech.co.za/news/government/356209/this-is-what-donald-trump-really-meant-when-he-called-south-africa-a-crime-ridden-mess/). She clarified that it was some misunderstanding and that Mr. Trump is actually supportive with trade and investment and she interpreted it as that it's about obstacles to increasing an incredible relationship with South Africa. She said that she has confidence in President Ramaphosa of South Africa that he can turn the country around and lower the crime rate. According to her, all Mr. Trump did was illustrating the problem areas and perhaps warning signs that those should not interfere.

One reason (which I think) is Mr. Trump repeatedly saying that he has done for the African American community more than anyone (except possibly President Lincoln). It is my opinion. Writers at [The Hill](https://thehill.com/opinion/white-house/511551-donald-trump-has-done-more-for-african-americans-than-we-think) agree with me. They have given wonderful reasons.

Comment: Maybe you should mention the reason in the article you link, which concludes that Trumps embrasure of racist rhetoric has forced a racial reckoning movement that otherwise would have continued to simmer under a more sympathetic president. quote: "The election of Trump and spread of his bigotry [sparked] unintended effects"

Comment: I agree mostly with the Nigerian point. I vacated to Nigeria as a Belgian Citizen for three months and I see a lot of Christianity and mega-churches insight. Like on one street in Lagos I saw 10 Churches. I was really amazed, @Wemnog

Answer (score -4):

American diplomats were free to speak without restrictions from the US government. President Donald Trump was not paying that much [attention](https://www.theafricareport.com/13778/why-africa-gives-thumbs-up-to-donald-trumps-america/) to Africa. He therefore gave space for American diplomats to act more freely in Africa in places like the Democratic Republic of Congo and Cameroon. American diplomats in Africa could take care to promote the classic values of America to the African people.

The capability to do the right thing is one of President Trump's clear strengths according to some Africans. A majority of Kenyans and Nigerians had a belief in President Trump to do the right thing in world [affairs](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/01/09/africa/africa-trump-pew-poll-intl/index.html) according to the Pew Research Center. 65% of Kenyans and 58% of Nigerians who were surveyed believed in Trump to do the right thing in international affairs. By contrast, 45% of Nigerians surveyed believed in Angela Merkel to do the right thing. Therefore 13% more Nigerians who were surveyed supported President Trump in comparison to Germany's Chancellor Angela Merkel. Some South Africans preferred President Trump over both Angela Merkel and the French President Emmanuel Macron.

There was not enough proof to sufficiently substantiate accusations of a rude remark made by President Trump about Nigerian immigrants to the USA in June 2017. ["Lies"](https://edition.cnn.com/2017/12/23/politics/donald-trump-oval-office-immigration/index.html) were reported in the New York Times about President Trump. Many of the African people were smart enough at the time to not lower their positive impressions of President Trump on the basis of false accusations. The First Lady of the USA Melania Trump has made a positive impression on some African people when she made a visit to Africa to further bolster President Trump's image abroad.

Perhaps the African people were so positive in their support of President Trump because they understand a need for positivity and support for one of the most powerful and important people in the USA. Africans have deserved for a long time to be influenced by positive leaders from around the world. By recognizing President Trump's positive capability to [do](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-51012853) the right thing some Africans merely expressed their gratitude towards the USA for its positive influence in their lives by President Trump.

As an author President Trump has sold many books in Africa, including in Nigeria. "[The Art of the Deal](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/oct/31/he-just-says-it-as-it-is-why-many-nigerians-support-donald-trump)" was a bestseller in Nigeria for many years. The US Vice-President Mike Pence and the Nigerian Vice-President Yemi Osinbajo are both Christians. Some Christians in Nigeria might have agreed with the relocation by President Trump of Jerusalem as the site of the US Israeli Embassy. Some Nigerians might have been impressed by President Trump's support for Christianity.

Under President Trump's positive leadership the US administration appointed top diplomatic staff including assistant secretary of state for Africa, Tibor Nagy and the administrator Mark Green. Both Mr. Nagy and Mr. Green visited Africa frequently they built up positive relationships with African leaders. Several of the ambassadorial appointments made by President Trump in relation to Africa have been [credible](https://www.cfr.org/in-brief/trumps-africa-policy-better-it-looks) appointments.

Parts of Africa have at times welcomed President Trump's government's security assistance in the promotion of dialogue and peace between African people. Light attack planes including six A-29 Super Tucano planes were sold by President Trump to Nigeria in 2017. The aircraft deal was worth $593 million and included thousands of bombs and rockets it might have increased support for President Trump among some Nigerians. The USAID government organization's [humanitarian](https://carnegieendowment.org/2019/05/03/stabilizing-northeast-nigeria-after-boko-haram-pub-79042) assistance in Nigeria increased from virtually nothing in 2014 to $291 million under President Trump's administration in 2017. Potential recruits to extremist groups in Nigeria are being helped through USAID interventions in order to prevent any recruitments into extremist groups.

Source Used:

1. https://edition.cnn.com/2017/12/23/politics/donald-trump-oval-office-immigration/index.html

Comment: You should think long and hard about what it is you want to say, and then make one big edit rather than loads of tiny, rapid-fire edits.

Comment: What do you mean by *"There was not enough proof to sufficiently substantiate accusations of a rude remark made by President Trump."*? I'd say [his insults are well documented](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/01/19/upshot/trump-complete-insult-list.html) and they were reported on even during and in the run up to his presidency.

Comment: This isn't a bad speculative answer, though the prose is curious.